# What is a single word to denote up-to-date-ness that would work in this context?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I want to add a word to the following list in my sentence to denote "up-to-date-ness" but am struggling to find the word:

> ...and addresses the accuracy, reliability, relevance, <up-to-date-ness> and completeness of data sources...

The best I can think of is "currency", but I'm not sure if there is a better term (that doesn't get confused with a money system).

Comment: just use uptodateness. it's overdue =)

Comment: Don't the other items in the list (esp. accuracy and relevance) cover being up-to-date? Information that is out of date isn't going to be accurate and may not be relevant or complete.

Comment: I think that is why there is the expression " to gain _currency_". Or maybe that is a different context.

Comment: Do you need to say accuracy *and* reliability? I think it could be argued that reliability implies accuracy and completeness.

Comment: There's an element of redundancy, but redundancy is sometimes justified by emphasis. Nonetheless, if you really want to emphasise something it's best to be more explicit: "take particular care to ensure..."

Answer (score 3):

There actually *is* a noun **up-to-dateness**.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*up-to-date*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up-to-date):

> **up-to-dateness** noun

In other words, the example sentence in the question is almost literally correct:

> ...and addresses the accuracy, reliability, relevance, *up-to-dateness*  and completeness of data sources...

Answer (score 2):

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/currentness#other-words) lists *currentness* as a noun form for the adjective *current*. It isn't widely used, but would be readily understood and (unlike *currency*) not confused with something else.

Comment: I thought of currentness too, but assumed it wasn't a word. Glad to see it is used. Yes, currency is too loaded with other meaning, even though it sounds the best. Thanks.

Comment: I've heard "currency" used in this context and didn't ever confuse it with money. The dictionary definition includes both meanings.

Answer (score 1):

"Age" can be a useful word in this context. We can certainly talk about the "age" of data. A downside is that it perhaps doesn't emphasize that the quality we presumably favor is how *new* the data is.

Answer (score 0):

[Data](https://www.google.com/search?q="recent+data+shows"&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGpafk58vjAhWHJTQIHVzkDO4Q_AUIFygB&biw=1280&bih=616) and [news](https://news.microsoft.com/recent-news/) often described as being [recent](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/recent), and the word also fits nicely into that particular list because it starts with re-. Recent refers to something that happened not so long ago, and hence implies up-to-dateness. Moreover, [recentness](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/recentness) itself is a word which An American Dictionary the English Language by Noah Webster (1828) defines as meaning:

> RE'CENTNESS, noun Newness; freshness; lateness of origin or occurrence; as the recentness of alluvial land; the recentness of news or of events

Granted, there is a slight difference between recent and up to date, in that hypothetically recent data could be inaccurate and hence detrimental to add to an update, but this minor distinction probably would not come into practical play very often.

Here is a relevant quotation which shows the word being used similarly from *[Fusionplex: Resolution of Data Inconsistencies in the Integration
of Heterogeneous Information Sources](https://cs.gmu.edu/~ami/research/publications/pdf/inffus06.pdf), by Amihai Motro and Philipp Anokhin (2006):

> Fusionplex is a system for integrating multiple heterogeneous and autonomous information sources that uses data fusion to
>   resolve factual inconsistencies among the individual sources. To accomplish this, the system relies on source features, which are
>   meta-data on the merits of each information source; for example, the recentness of the data, its accuracy, its availability, or its cost.

Comment: Thank you. I think after reading your defense and sources that "recentness" is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

**up to the minute**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up-to-the-minute) an idiom

> Describing something that is as current as is possible. The phrase is
>   sometimes hyphenated when used as a modifier before a noun.

As in:

> Which news station do you think will have the most up-to-the-minute
>   news on the hurricane?

Comment: That's an adjective.